# Setting maintenance mode on Shopware 5 shop from CLI?

Tags: shopware

I'm working on a python script to move a Shopware 5 installation from Host A, to Host B.
Part of the moving process is to set maintenance / service mode on the source server (Host A).

I've discovered when maintenance mode is enabled an entry for element_id 254 is made in the core_config_values table.

My problem is, the only way to get maintenance mode working from there is to clear template caches from the backend/admin panel. I've tried just clearing caches from the console. But it seems like the templates need to be warmed up before they come in effect just clearing caches is not enough. 
Is there anyway to do this from the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

to clear the cache via CLI just execute `bin/console sw:cache:clear`. To warm up the cache execute `bin/console sw:warm:http:cache`. This command also takes several option parameters to define which entities should be warmed up.

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann